# How to pass dynamic values to dynamic form array

Tags: angular

I am writing a dynamic angular form which has dynamic value and it works fine..but i want to be able to add more forms..but the problem is it keeps repeating values on the other form values because i am using ngModel and formArray.

Please how can i pass dynamic values to this dynamic form

I have tried the following

```
<div class="flex flex-col gt-xs:flex-row">
                    <mat-form-field class="w-full">

                        <input
                            id="measurement"
                            [(ngModel)]="people3"
                            [placeholder]="'Measurement'"
                            matInput
                            readonly
                            [formControlName]="'measurement'">

                            <mat-icon
                            class="icon-size-5"
                            matPrefix
                            [svgIcon]="'heroicons_outline:tag'"></mat-icon>

                        <mat-error *ngIf="employeeForm.get('measurement').hasError('required')">
                            Measurement
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
```

[image: This is the first form in my console]

[image: This is the first form]

Comment: Why are you mixing reactive forms directives (`formControlName`), with template based forms directives (`ngModel`)?  Use one, or the other, not both. See this: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms.

Comment: okay..but when i use reactive forms directives...i am not able to pass dynamic values to it..can u guide pls?

Comment: i am doing so, because the value is meant to be a dynamic value from database

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of how reactive forms works with angular

```
// ts code
@Component({
  ...
})
export class SomeComponent {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  public void ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      measurement: new FormControl('some initial value', [Validators.required]) // this is how you pass initial data
    })

  }
}
// html code
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
          <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" matInput
          formControlName="measurement">
</form>
```

Comment: my problem is...if the form is a dyanamic form where i click add button to add a new form....how can i use dynamic values(values from database) with the forms

Comment: example , how can i make the value of measurement unique for each dynamic form.